# unable to connect to sctp server running in docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-network, sctp

I am trying to containerize an SCTP server with below docker file

```
FROM  ubuntu:20.04

# Install utilities
RUN apt update && apt install -y libsctp-dev iputils-ping  net-tools curl gcc tcpdump vim

RUN mkdir -p /root/my_proj/
COPY . /root/my_proj/

WORKDIR /root/my_proj/
RUN   gcc sctpserver.c -o server -lsctp

CMD ["./server"]
```

Once docker container start running. I send a client request from my host machine to the sctp server running in docker.
But I get timeout on client. No pkt reaches to server as seen in tcpdump.

```
/home/ubuntu>sudo docker ps -a | grep sha
f99817f89f26   learnsha     "./server"     59 minutes ago   Up 59 minutes   0.0.0.0:62324->62324/sctp, :::62324->62324/sctp   learnsha-pr

/home/ubuntu>./client 
Enter data to send: abc                           --------> client is hung on host machine
Connection failed
connect(): Connection timed out
```

-- netstat on host shows closed connection

```
/home/ubuntu>netstat -n |  grep 62324
sctp                :::62324                           LISTEN     
sctp                0.0.0.0:62324                      LISTEN     
sctp       0      0 127.0.0.1:50638  127.0.0.1:62324   CLOSE -> why client connect is closed? 
/home/ubuntu>
```

sctp server code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/sctp.h>
#define MAX_BUFFER 1024
#define MY_PORT_NUM 62324 /* This can be changed to suit the need and should be same in server and client */

int
main ()
{
  int listenSock, connSock, ret, in, flags, i;
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
  struct sctp_initmsg initmsg;
  struct sctp_event_subscribe events;
  struct sctp_sndrcvinfo sndrcvinfo;
  char buffer[MAX_BUFFER + 1];

  listenSock = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_SCTP);
  if(listenSock == -1)
  {
      printf("Failed to create socket\n");
      perror("socket()");
      exit(1);
  }

  bzero ((void *) &servaddr, sizeof (servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (INADDR_ANY);
  servaddr.sin_port = htons (MY_PORT_NUM);

  ret = bind (listenSock, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof (servaddr));

  if(ret == -1 )
  {
      printf("Bind failed \n");
      perror("bind()");
      close(listenSock);
      exit(1);
  }

  /* Specify that a maximum of 5 streams will be available per socket */
  memset (&initmsg, 0, sizeof (initmsg));
  initmsg.sinit_num_ostreams = 5;
  initmsg.sinit_max_instreams = 5;
  initmsg.sinit_max_attempts = 4;
  ret = setsockopt (listenSock, IPPROTO_SCTP, SCTP_INITMSG,
      &initmsg, sizeof (initmsg));

  if(ret == -1 )
  {
      printf("setsockopt() failed \n");
      perror("setsockopt()");
      close(listenSock);
      exit(1);
  }

  ret = listen (listenSock, 5);
  if(ret == -1 )
  {
      printf("listen() failed \n");
      perror("listen()");
      close(listenSock);
      exit(1);
  }

  while (1)
    {

      char buffer[MAX_BUFFER + 1];
      int len;

      //Clear the buffer
      bzero (buffer, MAX_BUFFER + 1);

      printf ("Awaiting a new connection\n");

      connSock = accept (listenSock, (struct sockaddr *) NULL, (int *) NULL);
      if (connSock == -1)
      {
        printf("accept() failed\n");
        perror("accept()");
        close(connSock);
        continue;
      } else {
         printf ("New client connected....\n");
      }

      in = sctp_recvmsg (connSock, buffer, sizeof (buffer), (struct sockaddr *) NULL, 0, &sndrcvinfo, &flags);
      if( in == -1)
      {
          printf("Error in sctp_recvmsg\n");
          perror("sctp_recvmsg()");
          close(connSock);
          continue;
      }
      else
      {
          //Add '\0' in case of text data
          buffer[in] = '\0';

          printf (" Length of Data received: %d\n", in);
          printf (" Data : %s\n", (char *) buffer);
      }
      close (connSock);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

sctp client code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/sctp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#define MAX_BUFFER 1024
#define MY_PORT_NUM 62324 /* This can be changed to suit the need and should be same in server and client */

int
main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int connSock, in, i, ret, flags;
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
  struct sctp_status status;
  char buffer[MAX_BUFFER + 1];
  int datalen = 0;

  /*Get the input from user*/
  printf("Enter data to send: ");
  fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER, stdin);
  /* Clear the newline or carriage return from the end*/
  buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\r\n")] = 0;
  /* Sample input */
  //strncpy (buffer, "Hello Server", 12);
  //buffer[12] = '\0';
  datalen = strlen(buffer);

  connSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_SCTP);
  if (connSock == -1)
  {
      printf("Socket creation failed\n");
      perror("socket()");
      exit(1);
  }

  bzero ((void *) &servaddr, sizeof (servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_port = htons (MY_PORT_NUM);
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr ("127.0.0.1");

  ret = connect (connSock, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof (servaddr));
  if (ret == -1)
  {
      printf("Connection failed\n");
      perror("connect()");
      close(connSock);
      exit(1);
  }

  ret = sctp_sendmsg(connSock, (void *) buffer, (size_t) datalen, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  if(ret == -1 )
  {
    printf("Error in sctp_sendmsg\n");
    perror("sctp_sendmsg()");
  } else {
      printf("Successfully sent %d bytes data to server\n", ret);
  }

  close (connSock);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by doing the steps described here: [SCTP connections between Docker containers hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57963675/sctp-connections-between-docker-containers-hangs)

I was missing docker's host networking option while running the docker container.

`sudo docker run --net=host --name learnsha-pr -d -p 62324:62324/sctp learnsha`

SCTP support is still primitive in docker, as per the above-mentioned thread.